# Не получается вернуть пользователя после bcrypr.copmare

Tags: node.js

Поставил метку//Возвращает undefained

```
async getOneUser (req, res) {
        try{
            
                const { name, email, pass } = req.body
                
                db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE name=$1::text AND email=$2::text AND pass=$3::text', [name, email, pass] ,async (err, row) =>{
                    if(err){
                        console.log('Error executing query', err.stack);
                    }
                    
                      //console.log(pass, req)
                      
                        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(15);
                     const userPass =  bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.pass, salt)
                     
                    const hash = await bcrypt.compare(pass, userPass)

                   if(hash == true){
                        res.json(row.rows[0])//Возвращает undefained                     
                   }else{
                    res.json({"message": "Пароль введен не верно"})
                   }
```

Comment: `AND pass=$3::text` это что упячка?

Comment: в row нет rows или row.rows не массив или у массива row.rows нет 0 элемента